# mongo query with dates does not working as expected

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a query which is generated by the java driver below:

```
{ "$and" : [
    { "source_ip" : "10.0.71.218"} , 
    { "login" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2016-06-03T00:17:18.000Z"}}} , 
    { "$or" : [ 
        { "logout" : { "$exists" : false}} , 
        { "logout" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2016-06-03T00:17:18.000Z"}}}
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

This does not return the data properly. However, replacing the $date with ISODate(), fetches the data correctly. I do understand the 'strict' JSON usage by the driver. But I am not sure what I am missing/doing incorrectly with my java code below:

```
BasicDBObject logoutfilterQuery = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> lst_logoutfilter = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
lst_logoutfilter.add(new BasicDBObject("logout", new BasicDBObject("$exists", false)));
lst_logoutfilter.add(new BasicDBObject("logout", new BasicDBObject("$gte", logtime)));

logoutfilterQuery.put("$or", lst_logoutfilter);

BasicDBObject fetch_pppoe_user_query = new BasicDBObject();
List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("source_ip", sourceIP));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("login", new BasicDBObject("$lte", logtime)));
obj.add(logoutfilterQuery);

fetch_pppoe_user_query.put("$and", obj);
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
fields.put("user", 1);
fields.put("login", 1);
fields.put("logout", 1);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(fetch_pppoe_user_query, fields);
```

Any pointers will be hugely appreciated.

Sample doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5753f6821faca4f72daeb374"),
    "source_ip" : "10.0.181.163",
    "user" : "xyz@abc.com",
    "location" : "SOMEPLACE",
    "login" : ISODate("2016-06-01T12:43:35.000Z"),
    "logout" : ISODate("2016-06-01T12:45:18.000Z"),
    "connectionTimeInSeconds" : NumberLong(103),
    "datatransferIn" : NumberLong(54),
    "datatransferOut" : NumberLong(58),
    "packetsIn" : NumberLong(3),
    "packetsOut" : NumberLong(4)
}
```

Comment: How did you initialize the variable `logtime`?

Comment: That is a java.util.Date that is set elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Could you please include your sample document in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which takes timezone into consideration. I believe the problem is on **handling the timezone**. Normally, Mongo DB stores date in UTC timezone.

Please change the collection name and database name accordingly based on your requirement.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String sourceIP = "10.0.181.163";

    SimpleDateFormat logtimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'");
    logtimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    Date logtime = logtimeFormat.parse("2016-06-01T12:45:01.000Z");

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("localhost");
    BasicDBObject logoutfilterQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    List<BasicDBObject> lst_logoutfilter = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    lst_logoutfilter.add(new BasicDBObject("logout", new BasicDBObject("$exists", false)));
    lst_logoutfilter.add(new BasicDBObject("logout", new BasicDBObject("$gte", logtime)));

    logoutfilterQuery.put("$or", lst_logoutfilter);

    BasicDBObject fetch_pppoe_user_query = new BasicDBObject();
    List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    obj.add(new BasicDBObject("source_ip", sourceIP));
    obj.add(new BasicDBObject("login", new BasicDBObject("$lte", logtime)));
    obj.add(logoutfilterQuery);
    fetch_pppoe_user_query.put("$and", obj);
    System.out.println(fetch_pppoe_user_query);
    FindIterable<Document> findDoc = database.getCollection("dateissue").find(fetch_pppoe_user_query);
    for (Document doc : findDoc) {
        System.out.println(doc.toJson());
    }
}
```

Below is my Mongo Collection. Please note the date value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying this out. I had taken care of the dates being in UTC. Tried your code. Does not work in my environment. Now I am wondering if this is some version issue. Can you let me know you server, java-driver, jdk versions?

Comment: JDK - 1.8, Java-Driver - 3.2.2 and Mongo - 3.2.6

Comment: Ahh, I was on ancient versions of the server and driver, 2.6. With the above config you mentioned it works! Thanks a lot @notionquest. The code I had posted originally also works fine. So timezone was not the issue.

Comment: Am glad it worked for you. Am wondering what was the problem?